# How to run shell commands with root privileges in Java

Tags: java, shell, root

I need to run shell commands (in my case `ipfw`) in Java with root privileges. I use `ProcessBuilder` to run commands with no privileges:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("ls","/").start();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

String s;
while((s=br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

This code work fine but I need to run something like `sudo` *root command*. How can I do?

I need to run this program in Eclipse, Mac OS X 10.6.8

Edit: for now I use `sudo java` *nameclass* from terminal but in this way I have to manually add all the referenced classes.

Answer (score 6):

Easy!

1. Set up your `sudoers` to not require a password for `ipfw`:

   ```
   user = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/ipfw
   ```
2. Use `sudo` as usual.

Comment: `sudo visudo`. Edit to your heart's content.

Comment: Do I must add this line under `# User privilege specification`?

Comment: Yes, you should add it there.

Comment: I've put the line there but it response me with error in that line. I've also substituted `user` with _myusername_ but the error is the same.