# priv-app how to read another app's database

Tags: android, sqlite, migration, system, privileges

Our app's package name is changing and when our app is released we need to migrate some data from the old app to our new one.  Our apps are in the priv-app folder on these devices.  On first start, the new app needs to read a table in our old app's database.

Does anyone have any experience or knowledge that could point me in the right direction for a solution?  Another constraint, we cannot update the old app again.

Comment: You will need a rooted phone to that. What you are trying to do is a serious breach of Android security. See :-        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244212/how-to-read-database-of-another-application

Comment: @JonGoodwin  Is there no other way? Even with an app in the priv-app folder?

Comment: If you have not already provided export capability in your old app, then you have painted yourself into a corner. You have 3 options to access the old data (1) root all phones with old app (2) updated old app (3) do NOT change the package name. (which is the same as (2) really.)

Comment: /system/priv-app won't help you because you will still need root to change permissions.

Comment: Thank you!  Its not what I was looking for but I appreciate your help.